# UWP - StorageFile to ImageSource obeying MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have multiple `StorageFile`s available as `Task<StorageFile>`s in my ViewModel, I want to bind an Image in my View to it.

A BitmapImage shouldn't be made in the ViewModel, because it's in the XAML namespace and requires the UI thread (which I fail to do).

How should I tackle this problem? Using a ValueConverter can't be done, as opening the StorageFile is async...

PS: I can't use an URI, the StorageFile is located in the LocalCache folder...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just use `Path` property from `StorageFile` class:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageItems}"
            Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="1">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path}"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Where `ImageItems` it's `public List<StorageFile> ImageItems` property

Comment: I am shocked that this works, it feels like hacking around the UWP sandbox. All solutions I've seen are creating the ImageSource in code, this lets XAML do that. Also it looks like you can set `Image.Source` to the binding directly, no need for the BitmapImage. Thanks!

Comment: I expanded from `Image.Source` to `BitmapImage` so yu can user `DecodePixelWidth` property (memory leak issue)

Comment: I can't find an issue describing a memory leak, just an issue that the image is usually larger than display resolution, meaning memory is wasted. My images are always below display resolution though.