# Show an image from local computer in Image with model binding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, model-binding, xamarin.uwp

I want to implement an feature like that, an image control in xamarin.uwp, a user will select the image by file picker, and set the the image to the image control.

As far as I know, I could not set the local path directly to the file path.

How can I use with the file stream?

Update1:

xaml

```
<Image  Grid.Row="3" Source="{Binding Image}"></Image>
```

ImagePageViewModel

```
public class ImagePageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ImagePageViewModel()
    {

    }
    private ImageSource _image;
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _image, value); }
    }        

    private DelegateCommand _imageSelect;
    public DelegateCommand ImageSelect =>
        _imageSelect ?? (_imageSelect = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteImageSelect));

    async void ExecuteImageSelect()
    {
        try
        {
            var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker
            {
                ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
                SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
            };
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

            Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {                       
                    Image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => fileStream.AsStream());                       
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ImageUri = "";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Have you try **ImageSource.FromStream**

Comment: Do you mean define propperty with `ImageSource` and use `ImageSource.FromStream`? If so, I already have tried and did not work.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @PhatHuynh Please check the update.

Comment: Check this one: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562861/uwp-storagefile-to-imagesource-obeying-mvvm)

Comment: @PhatHuynh It's an old thread. I am using Xamarian.forms, there is no ` <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path}"/>`.

Comment: And you use **Windows.Storage.StorageFile** in **Xamarin.Forms** project?

Comment: @PhatHuynh Yes, you could check this code `Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();` in my post.

Comment: So you use **Xamarin.Forms** to build **Windows.UWP** app. That's weird. In debug console does it throw any exception log?

Comment: @PhatHuynh There is no error. Can you share a working demo?

Comment: I use [This package](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to pick file instead of **Windows.Storage.StorageFile** and use file like you did, nothing different but it works.